# Store the nth class name from a HTML tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically generated `div` that receives two generated classes applied to it. For example, I have :

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

Then after I mess with it using some Javascript, it becomes:

```
<div class="container post post-hello-world">...</div>
```

For this example how can I grab the third class (`post-hello-world`) and store it somewhere to be used for something else in my Javascript code using pure Javascript?

Comment: Is the class guaranteed to always be the 3rd class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `classList` and `item` if the class you want is always third:

```
var className = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].classList.item(2);
```

**See**

- [MDN: Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/62oqxfkk/)

Comment: Beat me to it! Great answer! Hard to type on mobile ;)

Comment: Awesome answer! Would a failsafe for this to check the class that has the prefix `post-`, then use that as well? The class will always have `post-` on it.

Comment: @privateer35 Sure, you can verify the class name. Whether it is necessary or not depends on what you are doing after grabbing it. If it's possible that another class name, not starting with `post-`, is present and if this would break something, then yes, you should definitely check it.

Comment: @privateer35 Also, as it seems you're storing information in the class name that is not necessarily related to CSS classes, you might also consider using [`data`-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for this purpose. It would help to decouple the JavaScript creating an attribute like `data-post-title="hello-word"` that works solely with your script.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Awesome, I thought a check would be a good idea. And unfortunately I'm working with a CMS that places them within HTML tags though I wish I had the option of using data-attributes instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".container");
var thirdClass = element.classList[2];
```

You may also what to use some checks to make sure that the element has 3 or more classes. Something like `if(element.classList.length >= 3)`